# Подтвердить html форму

Tags: python, http, urllib, requests

Есть такая вот форма:

```html
<div class="formulation clearfix"><h4 class="accesshide">Текст</h4><input type="hidden" name="q1437458:12_:sequencecheck" value="1"><div class="qtext">блабла</div><div class="ablock"><div class="prompt">текст:</div><div class="answer"><div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q1437458:12_answer" value="0" id="q1437458:12_answer0"><label for="q1437458:12_answer0">a. один</label> </div>
<div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q1437458:12_answer" value="1" id="q1437458:12_answer1"><label for="q1437458:12_answer1">b. десять</label> </div>
<div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q1437458:12_answer" value="2" id="q1437458:12_answer2"><label for="q1437458:12_answer2">c. три</label> </div>
<div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q1437458:12_answer" value="3" id="q1437458:12_answer3"><label for="q1437458:12_answer3">d. 4</label> </div>
<div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q1437458:12_answer" value="4" id="q1437458:12_answer4"><label for="q1437458:12_answer4">e. 2</label> </div>
</div></div><div class="im-controls"><input type="submit" id="q1437458:12_-submit" name="q1437458:12_-submit" value="Submit" class="submit btn"></div></div>
```

Как симитировать выбор первого варианта и нажатия на кнопку "Submit" с помощью библиотеки requests?
Делал так:

```
payload = {'q1437458:4_answer': '0', 'q1437458:4_-submit': 'Submit'}
r = s.post(ur, data=payload)
```

но почему то не работает. В вебе почти не разбраюсь так что прошу не пинать.

Каждому ответу присваивается статус - `incorrect/correct/notyetanswered`. Сервер возращает мне `<div id="q4" class="que multichoice immediatefeedback notyetanswered">`

Форма до чека:

```html
<div id="q1" class="que multichoice immediatefeedback notyetanswered">
  <div class="info">
    <h3 class="no">Питання <span class="qno">1</span></h3>
    <div class="state">Не завершено</div>
    <div class="grade">Макс. оцінка до 1,00</div>
    <div class="questionflag editable" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="text" aria-live="assertive" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_24">
      <input type="hidden" name="q1439910:1_:flagged" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" value="qaid=24910476&amp;qubaid=1439910&amp;qid=1285151&amp;slot=1&amp;checksum=30c911ce27cf7dd9ed3b562a4e53b861&amp;sesskey=6gFuOSeJFV&amp;newstate=" class="questionflagpostdata">
      <input type="hidden" class="questionflagvalue" id="q1439910:1_:flaggedcheckbox" name="q1439910:1_:flagged" value="0">
      <input type="image" class="questionflagimage" src="https://msn.khnu.km.ua/theme/image.php/clean/core/1464491009/i/unflagged" title="Відмітити це питання для майбутнього посилання" alt="Не помічено"><span class="questionflagtext" title="Відмітити це питання для майбутнього посилання">Відмітити питання</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_641">
    <div class="formulation clearfix" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_640">
      <h4 class="accesshide">Текст питання</h4>
      <input type="hidden" name="q1439910:1_:sequencecheck" value="1">
      <div class="qtext">EventHandler середовища .NET Framework це</div>
      <div class="ablock" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_639">
        <div class="prompt">Виберіть одну відповідь:</div>
        <div class="answer" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_638">
          <div class="r0" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_637">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="0" id="q1439910:1_answer0">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer0">a. Вбудована структура</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r1">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="1" id="q1439910:1_answer1">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer1">b. вбудований тип даних</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r0">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="2" id="q1439910:1_answer2">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer2">c. вбудований тип події</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r1">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="3" id="q1439910:1_answer3">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer3">d. вбудований тип делегата</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r0">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="4" id="q1439910:1_answer4">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer4">e. Інша відповідь</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="im-controls">
        <input type="submit" id="q1439910:1_-submit" name="q1439910:1_-submit" value="Відмітити" class="submit btn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И форма после чека:

```html
<div id="q1" class="que multichoice immediatefeedback notyetanswered">
  <div class="info">
    <h3 class="no">Питання <span class="qno">1</span></h3>
    <div class="state">Не завершено</div>
    <div class="grade">Макс. оцінка до 1,00</div>
    <div class="questionflag editable" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="text" aria-live="assertive" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_24">
      <input type="hidden" name="q1439910:1_:flagged" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" value="qaid=24910476&amp;qubaid=1439910&amp;qid=1285151&amp;slot=1&amp;checksum=30c911ce27cf7dd9ed3b562a4e53b861&amp;sesskey=6gFuOSeJFV&amp;newstate=" class="questionflagpostdata">
      <input type="hidden" class="questionflagvalue" id="q1439910:1_:flaggedcheckbox" name="q1439910:1_:flagged" value="0">
      <input type="image" class="questionflagimage" src="https://msn.khnu.km.ua/theme/image.php/clean/core/1464491009/i/unflagged" title="Відмітити це питання для майбутнього посилання" alt="Не помічено"><span class="questionflagtext" title="Відмітити це питання для майбутнього посилання">Відмітити питання</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_641">
    <div class="formulation clearfix" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_640">
      <h4 class="accesshide">Текст питання</h4>
      <input type="hidden" name="q1439910:1_:sequencecheck" value="1">
      <div class="qtext">EventHandler середовища .NET Framework це</div>
      <div class="ablock" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_639">
        <div class="prompt">Виберіть одну відповідь:</div>
        <div class="answer" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_638">
          <div class="r0" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_637">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="0" id="q1439910:1_answer0">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer0" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1464624154550_645">a. Вбудована структура</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r1">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="1" id="q1439910:1_answer1">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer1">b. вбудований тип даних</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r0">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="2" id="q1439910:1_answer2">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer2">c. вбудований тип події</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r1">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="3" id="q1439910:1_answer3">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer3">d. вбудований тип делегата</label>
          </div>
          <div class="r0">
            <input type="radio" name="q1439910:1_answer" value="4" id="q1439910:1_answer4">
            <label for="q1439910:1_answer4">e. Інша відповідь</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="im-controls">
        <input type="submit" id="q1439910:1_-submit" name="q1439910:1_-submit" value="Відмітити" class="submit btn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит не работает? Какой ответ возвращает сервер?

Comment: @Donil в топик добавил.

Comment: Первое, что бросается в глаза - это то, что у Вас имена инпутов указаны неправильно. Например у submit'a имя `q1437458:12_-submit`, а не `q1437458:4_-submit, то же касается и выбранного значения

Comment: @Donil в запросе все было правильно, просто сюда кинул форму 4 вопроса. Вот, еще, когда все это дело монитотрю через dev. tools в chrome, после чека там присваивают какие то id, в топике закинул форму до чека и после.